# Read date value using two way binding typescript

Tags: html, angular, date, typescript

I am using default date input HTML element to render datepicker in my page. But, the default value in the page is showing as "mm/dd/yyyy" even after two way binding is applied. What is wrong with below code?

**My HTML page:**

```
 <div class='input-group date datepicker'>                            
     <input id="dtDate" type="date" [(ngModel)]="todayDate" />
 </div>
```

**My .ts file**

```
  private todayDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

When i read "todayDate" value, i am getting right value. But in UX, the default value is showing as "mm/dd/yyyy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input [ngModel]="todayDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="todayDate = $event" type="date" name="todayDate"/>
```

I think your code must be like that.